# Aurelia withInterceptor method

Tags: aurelia, fetch-api

How to break promise **chain** and go to the catch method, below my code :

```
.withInterceptor({
    response(response,d) {
        console.log(`Received ${response.status} ${response.url}`);
        // Catch
        if(!response.ok){
            return response.json().then(err => {
                throw new Error(err.faultMessage);
            });
        }
        return response.json();
    }
});

get(url: String, object: Object = {}) {
    let promise = this.httpClient.fetch(`${url}?${$.param(object)}`, {
        method: 'GET'
    }).catch(e=>this.catchError(e));
    return promise;
}

catchError(msg){
    this.notifySrvc.notify(msg,'error');
}
```

From another place i call this get method like this :

```
srvc.get('url',{}).then(function(res){console.log(res)})
```

What happens is that the then get called and the catch at the same time how to change this strange behavior ?

Comment: As far as I know, you can't break the promise chain with the interceptor. You can examine the contents of the response, but you can't intercept it or edit it. [Here's a link to a GitHub issue](https://github.com/SpoonX/aurelia-api/issues/178) I created last year on the Aurelia-API Repo, regarding the drawbacks of the Aurelia-Fetch interceptors. I think this covers what you're talking about?

Comment: Thank you for your response, I found another solution by using promise object and based on the fetch api response if ok or not i resolve or reject the request.